# Visibility Graph Toolbox for Python

Tags: motion-planning, python

I'm searching for a python toolbox/library to do visibility graph based motion planning. I have searched on the internet, but couldn't find anything. I'm probably missing out...

Is there any package, you can recommend me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [VisiLibity](http://www.visilibity.org/) implementation appears to have python bindings.

Comment: I saw that one, but I thought it was limited to C++ and I had to wrap it or so...

Comment: Did that answer your question? If so would you mind marking it as such? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately it did not help. Otherwise I would have accepted your answer. I was already aware of Visibility; it is simply google first page result...

Comment: It has python bindings (or at least it says so on the website).

Comment: While VisiLibity does appear to have Python bindings, they are not packaged in a way that is immediately usable by someone without experience compiling SWIG/Python.